# glob() absolute filepath returning no results

Tags: php, glob

Im using glob() to retrieve a load of photos matching a rule. the page is located in `/stocklist/222/page.php.` the photos are located in `/stocklist/photo/`

i've tried using the code below, but it seems to return no results.

```
$photo = glob("/photo/".$row['Scientific']."?.jpg");
```

i have a feeling it's looking in `stocklist/222/photo`

EDIT:

Following suggestions (@Niels Keurentjes, @Gasim), ive used

```
echo getcwd() ;
$photo = (glob('/var/www/web/stocklist/photo/'.$row['Scientific'].'*.jpg'));
print_r(glob('/var/www/web/stocklist/photo/'.$row['Scientific'].'*.jpg'));
```

Which produces the following:

```
/var/www/web/stocklist

Array ( [0] => /var/www/web/stocklist/photo/Pituophis deppei jani.jpg 
[1] => /var/www/web/stocklist/photo/Pituophis deppei jani1.jpg )
```

But the images are displaying as missing files.

Comment: Use `getcwd` to find the current working directory, and adjust the relative path accordingly.

Comment: You're not using an absolute filepath with your glob() call though, you're using a relative path.... whicg raises the question of relative to where

Comment: Could you show ana exemple from your photos folder? and what's the content of `$row['Scientific']`?

Comment: `glob(dirname(__DIR__).'/photo/'.$row['Scientific'].'?.jpg');` - `dirname(__DIR__)` finds the directory of the current directory, which means the previous directory, or "../"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for you could be:

```
$photo = "../photo/" . $row['Scientific'] . ".jpg";
```

[glob()][1] returns an array not the string.

Try doing the following to understand more of what `glob` is doing:

```
print_r(glob("../photo/".$row['Scientific']."/*"));
```

As a result you will have an array with all `.jpg` files in given folder, e.g.:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /stocklist/222/photo/1.jpg
    [1] => /stocklist/222/photo/2.jpg
    [2] => /stocklist/222/photo/3.jpg
    [3] => /stocklist/222/photo/4.jpg
    [4] => /stocklist/222/photo/5.jpg
    [5] => /stocklist/222/photo/6.jpg
    [6] => /stocklist/222/photo/7.jpg  
)
```

###EDIT 1:

In case your example is correct you could just access your first photo in array using:

```
$photo[0];
```

###EDIT 2:

Another problem in your code, is that you're using `?` as wildcard operator but it's not recognized, and should be replaced with `*` instead.

###EDIT 3:

According to your last update, you have spaces in your filenames - it's a bad practice, from my point of view, you should fix it!

###EDIT 4:

Example, of how I would use it further, instead of using `for` loop:

```
$photos = glob('/var/www/web/stocklist/photo/'.$row['Scientific'].'*.jpg');

if (!empty($photos))
  {
    echo "<ul id='slide'>";
    foreach ($photos as $photo)
      {
        echo "<li><img src='" . $photo . "' alt='' class='img-right'></li>";
      }
    echo "</ul>";
      
  }
```

---

Acording to [PHP: glob - Manual ][1]:

**Description:**

> The glob() function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern according to the rules used by the libc glob() function, which is similar to the rules used by common shells.

**Return Values:**

> Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error.
> [1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed answer. ill take a look and have a play an let you know how i get on.

Comment: Bit more info added above and Im using the glob() array with the following code to print it out:

    `$length = count($photo);
    if($length) {
    echo"<ul id='slide'>";
   for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
   echo "<li><img src='".$photo[$i]."' alt='".$row['Name']."' class='img-right'></li>";}`